# Find documents with array field that only contains specific values and nothing else

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Consider this collection:

```
{
  { name: 'first', toys: ['doll', 'car', 'doll'],
  { name: 'second', toys: ['doll', 'car'],
  { name: 'third', toys: ['doll', 'car', 'bricks'],
  { name: 'fourth', toys: ['doll', 'bricks'],
  { name: 'fifth', toys: []
}
```

I want to query for documents whose `toys` field is an array that only contains `doll` and `car`. In this case, both `first` and `second` should match. `first` matches because `doll` and `car` can be repeated in the array, `third` doesn't match because no other value must be present in the array, and `fourth` and `fifth` don't match because they don't contain both `doll` and `car`.

Using `$all` and `$in` doesn't work for me because they match `third`. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach would be to use the aggregate operator [`$setEquals`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setEquals/) which compares two or more arrays and returns true if they have the same distinct elements and false otherwise:

```
db.collection.find({
    '$expr': { 
        '$setEquals': ['$toys', ['doll', 'car']] 
    }
})
```

---

Another alternative is [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) which takes two arrays and performs a relative complement of the second array relative to the first and this operation does not require elements to be in order.

In your case use the result from [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) to check if its empty and set that as basis for your query.

For example the operation

```
{ $setDifference: [ ['doll', 'car', 'doll'], ['doll', 'car'] ] } => []
```

and this

```
{ $setDifference: [ ['car', 'doll', 'doll'], ['doll', 'car'] ] } => []
```

as well as

```
{ $setDifference: [ ['car', 'doll'], ['doll', 'car'] ] } => []
```

or

```
{ $setDifference: [ ['doll', 'car'], ['doll', 'car'] ] } => []
```

but

```
{ $setDifference: [ ['doll', 'car', 'bricks'], ['doll', 'car'] ] } => ['bricks']
```

Using the logic above, as a helper you can take the length of the array result with [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) and check if it's 0 for your query expression with [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)

---

Final query:

```
db.collection.find({
    '$expr': {
        '$eq': [
            { '$size': { 
                '$setDifference': [ 
                    '$toys', 
                    ['doll', 'car'] 
                ] 
            } },
            0
        ]
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this gets very close. However it doesn't exclude documents for which `toys` is an empty array, or contains either `doll` or `car`. How can I modify your answer to include this constraint? I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @UcheOzoemena You can use `$setEquals` which is better

Comment: Awesome yes I've seen and used `setEquals`! Thanks for the update! Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Following query retrieves if the document is having either `car` or `doll` or both. But it won't retrieve empty array records.

```
db.getCollection('toys').find({
    $and: [{
        toys: {$elemMatch: {$in: ["doll", "car"]}}
    },
    {
        toys: {$not: {$elemMatch: {$nin: ["doll", "car"]}}}
    }]})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this also includes documents that contain an empty array or only `doll` or `car`. Any ideas for how to make it more specific?

Comment: Updated the answer. It might not what you expected but close enough.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the update but i need it to be both only. It needs to contain all of the supplied array members, no more and no less.